# Getting nested (joined) tables to display in the OpenAPI interface provided by FastAPI and SQLModel

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

I'm having trouble understanding how to display the children data in a one-to-many relationship using FastAPI and SQLModel. I'm using Python 3.10.3, FastAPI version 0.78.0 and SQLModel version 0.0.6. Here's a simplified version of the parent/child database models:

```
from datetime import datetime
from email.policy import default
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel, Relationship

class CustomerBase(SQLModel):
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("email"),)

    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    email: str
    active: bool | None = True

class Customer(CustomerBase, table=True):
    id: int | None =Field(primary_key=True, default=None)

class CustomerCreate(CustomerBase):
    pass

class CustomerRead(CustomerBase):
    id: int

class CustomerReadWithCalls(CustomerRead):
    calls: list["CallRead"] = []

class CallBase(SQLModel):
    duration: int
    cost_per_minute: int | None = None
    customer_id: int | None = Field(default=None, foreign_key="customer.id")
    created: datetime = Field(nullable=False, default=datetime.now().date())

class Call(CallBase, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(primary_key=True)

class CallCreate(CallBase):
    pass

class CallRead(CallBase):
    id: int

class CallReadWithCustomer(CallRead):
    customer: CustomerRead | None
```

Here is the API Route:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException, Depends, Query
from rbi_app.crud.customer import (
    get_customers,
    get_customer,
)
from rbi_app.models import (
    CustomerRead,
    CustomerReadWithCalls,
)
from rbi_app.database import Session, get_session

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/customers/", status_code=200, response_model=list[CustomerRead])
def read_customers(
    email: str = "",
    offset: int = 0,
    limit: int = Query(default=100, lte=100),
    db: Session = Depends(get_session)
):
    return get_customers(db, email, offset=offset, limit=limit)

@router.get("/customers/{customer_id}", status_code=200, response_model=CustomerReadWithCalls)
def read_customer(id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_session)):
    customer = get_customer(db, id)
    if customer is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=f"Customer not found for {id=}")
    return customer
```

And here are the queries to the database the API Route endpoints make:

```
from sqlmodel import select
from rbi_app.database import Session
from rbi_app.models import (
    Customer,
    CustomerCreate,
)
# from rbi_app.schemas.customer import CustomerCreate
    
def get_customer(db: Session, id: int):
    return db.get(Customer, id)
    
def get_customers(db: Session, email: str = "", offset: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    if email:
        return db.exec(select(Customer).where(Customer.email == email)).first()
    return db.exec(select(Customer).offset(offset).limit(limit).order_by(Customer.id)).all()
```

When I navigate to a route to get all a customer my query runs and I get a customer, but there is no "calls" list attribute in the customer. The OpenAPI display shows a "calls" attribute, but it's empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without the API route part it is difficoult to say what's wrong. Also, we're missing the query, but I guess that pydantic initializes the `calls` field with an empty array because you're not extracting/adding the `calls` to the response.

Comment: Maybe it is because the calls are not eager loaded. Check [this comment](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/130#issuecomment-943400758) in a SQLModel issues for more information.

Comment: You're correct, I should have included the API Route and the actual queries. Changed the OP to change this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here seems to be that you did not define the relationship on the `Customer` model (or the `Call` module). Since you query the database with the `Customer` model and it has no `calls` attribute, none of that data is present in the object returned by your `get_customer` function.

Even though your route defines the `CustomerReadWithCalls` as a response model, upon calling it, the object of that class can only ever be instantiated with the data returned by your route handler function, which is your `Customer` instance in this case. Since that does not even have the `calls` attribute (let alone the data), the `CustomerReadWithCalls` object is  essentially created with the default value that you defined for the `calls` field -- the empty list.

Adding

```py
    calls: list["Call"] = Relationship(back_populates="customer")
```

to your `Customer` model **should** be enough.

(But as a side note, for me the route documentation only works properly, when I explicitly update the references on the `CustomerReadWithCalls` model after the `CallRead` definition.)

Here is a full working example.

`models.py`

```py
from datetime import datetime

from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint
from sqlmodel import Field, Relationship, SQLModel


class CustomerBase(SQLModel):
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("email"),)

    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    email: str
    active: bool | None = True


class Customer(CustomerBase, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(primary_key=True, default=None)

    calls: list["Call"] = Relationship(back_populates="customer")


class CustomerCreate(CustomerBase):
    pass


class CustomerRead(CustomerBase):
    id: int


class CustomerReadWithCalls(CustomerRead):
    calls: list["CallRead"] = []


class CallBase(SQLModel):
    duration: int
    cost_per_minute: int | None = None
    customer_id: int | None = Field(default=None, foreign_key="customer.id")
    created: datetime = Field(nullable=False, default=datetime.now().date())


class Call(CallBase, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(primary_key=True, default=None)

    customer: Customer | None = Relationship(back_populates="calls")


class CallCreate(CallBase):
    pass


class CallRead(CallBase):
    id: int


# After the definition of `CallRead`, update the forward reference to it:
CustomerReadWithCalls.update_forward_refs()


class CallReadWithCustomer(CallRead):
    customer: CustomerRead | None
```

`routes.py`

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Depends
from sqlmodel import Session, SQLModel, create_engine

from .models import CustomerReadWithCalls, Customer, Call


api = FastAPI()

sqlite_file_name = 'database.db'
sqlite_url = f'sqlite:///{sqlite_file_name}'
engine = create_engine(sqlite_url, echo=True)


@api.on_event('startup')
def initialize_db():
    SQLModel.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)

    # For testing:
    with Session(engine) as session:
        customer = Customer(first_name="Foo", last_name="Bar", email="foo@bar.com")
        call1 = Call(duration=123)
        call2 = Call(duration=456)
        customer.calls.extend([call1, call2])
        session.add(customer)
        session.commit()


def get_session() -> Session:
    session = Session(engine)
    try:
        yield session
    finally:
        session.close()


def get_customer(db: Session, id: int):
    return db.get(Customer, id)


@api.get("/customers/{customer_id}", status_code=200, response_model=CustomerReadWithCalls)
def read_customer(customer_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_session)):
    customer = get_customer(db, customer_id)
    if customer is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=f"Customer not found for {customer_id=}")
    return customer
```

Starting the API server and sending `GET` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/customers/1` gives me

```json
{
  "first_name": "Foo",
  "last_name": "Bar",
  "email": "foo@bar.com",
  "active": true,
  "id": 1,
  "calls": [
    {
      "duration": 123,
      "cost_per_minute": null,
      "customer_id": 1,
      "created": "2022-08-16T00:00:00",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "duration": 456,
      "cost_per_minute": null,
      "customer_id": 1,
      "created": "2022-08-16T00:00:00",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Daniil, this helps a lot. The back_populates thing I missed completely, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why there is a need for the `Create` classes since they don't just a `pass`. And also the need for extra `Read` classes with `id` in it, since the other classes do have an id.

Comment: 1) The `Create` classes are just for the sake of completeness and to illustrate that you would set them up the same way as the other specialized subclasses by adding specific fields as needed. Other than illustration, they obviously do not serve any purpose in this specific example. @moth

Comment: 2) The `Read` classes **do** serve a purpose and you **do** have to specify the `id` field because their parent classes (ending in `Base`) **do not** have an `id` field (by design) and the `Read` classes usually need to mirror the actual table mappers (those created with `table=True`) but without the relationship attributes. A lot of this is heavily mirroring the suggested class inheritance structures in the [SQLModel documentation](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/fastapi/multiple-models/). Check it out for more details. @moth

Comment: I don't understand why does it need to mirror exactly the same as the table mappers. Anyways I will post an example and link here, perhaps you could help me out, thanks.

Comment: here is a link to my question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74719687/getting-joined-tables-from-sqlmodel-as-a-nested-responde-model-in-fastapi