# getting joined tables from sqlmodel as a nested responde model in fastapi

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, sqlmodel

I cannot figure it out how to display a one to many relationship using fastapi and sqlmodel. I've read through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72870598/getting-nested-joined-tables-to-display-in-the-openapi-interface-provided-by-f/73372947?noredirect=1#comment131875135_73372947) but my case seems to be slightly different. Specially in the function call.

This is my `schemas.py`:

```py
from typing import Optional
from sqlmodel import Field, Relationship, SQLModel

class BinaryBase(SQLModel):
    product_id: int
    software_install_path: Optional[str] = None
    host_id: int = Field(foreign_key="host.id", nullable=False)


class Binary(BinaryBase, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    host_id: int = Field(foreign_key="host.id", nullable=False)
    host: "Host" = Relationship(back_populates="binaries")


class HostBase(SQLModel):
    name: str
    region: Optional[str] = None
    os_version: Optional[str] = None
    network: Optional[int] = None


class Host(HostBase, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    binaries: list[Binary] = Relationship(back_populates='host')


class HostReadWithBinary(HostBase):
    bins: list[HostBase] = []


class BinaryReadWithHost(BinaryBase):
    host: BinaryBase
```

And this is my `main.py`:

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from sqlmodel import Session, col, select

...

@app.get(
    "/binaries/",
    response_model=list[HostReadWithBinary]
)
def get_binary(name: Optional[str] = None, session: Session = Depends(get_session)) -> list[HostReadWithBinary]:
    query = select(Host).limit(100)
    if name:
        query = query.where(col(Host.name).contains(name.lower()))

    return session.exec(query).all()
```

The `Host` table represents the `1` part and the `Binary` table represents the `many` part. I would like to get a response of all the `BinaryBase` attributes for all the hosts eagerly. But what I get is this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "hkl20014889",
    "region": "HK",
    "os_version": "Red Hat 6.10",
    "network": 3,
    "bins": []
  },
  {
    "name": "hkl20016283",
    "region": "HK",
    "os_version": "Red Hat 6.10",
    "network": 3,
    "bins": []
  },
....
```

Theoreticaly `bins` should hold the attributes of the `Host` table when `id` in `Host` joins `host_id` in Binary.

Comment: Please try to make code examples in your questions reproducible. Aside from the missing imports, there is no code showing what `app` or `get_session` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to realize that when you define a `response_model` for a route, it will always try to parse whatever data comes out of your route handler function (`get_binary` in this case) through that model. This is done by essentially calling the [`.from_orm`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#orm-mode-aka-arbitrary-class-instances) method on the response model, which goes through all fields defined on it and tries to find **corresponding** attributes (i.e. with the same names) on the object you pass to it.

The model you specified (in a list, but the argument stands) is `HostReadWithBinary`. Aside from the fields defined on its parent model `HostBase` it only has the field `bins`, which is supposed to be a list of `HostBase`.

First of all, I think you *meant* to declare that `bins` field to be of the type `list[BinaryBase]`, not `list[HostBase]`. If you had named the field correctly, this would have caused an error, but this is where your second mistake comes in.

You also named the field on your response model `bins`, but your handler function performs a query that returns a list of `Host` model instances. That model **does not have** a `bins` field. It has a field named `binaries`. This means that when the `from_orm` method gets to the `HostReadWithBinary.bins` field, it checks if the corresponding `Host` instance has an attribute named `bins`. It does not find one, but no problem because you set a default for `HostReadWithBinary.bins`, namely the empty list `[]`, so that is what is set on each of the resulting response model instances.

You should therefore be able to fix your error by changing the response model definition like this:

```py
class HostReadWithBinary(HostBase):
    binaries: list[BinaryBase] = []
```

Alternatively, you can change the name of the relationship field on your `Host` model:

```py
class Host(HostBase, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    bins: list[Binary] = Relationship(back_populates='host')


class HostReadWithBinary(HostBase):
    bins: list[BinaryBase] = []
```

They need to be the same, otherwise parsing an object of one model to the other will not work (properly).

---

Side note: You also mistakenly annotated the `host` field on `BinaryReadWithHost` with `BinaryBase` instead of `HostBase`.

**PS**: I also just noticed a minor mistake related to type annotations. You declare the return type of your route handler function to be `list[HostReadWithBinary]`, but that is not what it returns. It returns `list[Host]`. This is part of the misunderstanding with the response models. The **decorated** version of your route is what returns `list[HostReadWithBinary]`. Your route handler `get_binary` by itself (i.e. before decoration) returns `list[Host]`, which is *then* passed to the wrapper around it and that wrapper parses it to `list[HostReadWithBinary]` and sends that data on its way (to the client eventually). This wrapper action obviously happens behind the scenes and is part of that FastAPI decorator magic.

Comment: this is very helpful, thanks. I will read more on your first paragraph considerations, especially the `from_orm` method that looks for corresponding attributes. I could not imagine the `binaries` attributes can be seen by `HostReadWithBinary` since this class inherits from `HostBase` and not from `Host` which contains the `binaries` attribute. How is it even possible for the it to be available to `HostReadWithBinary` ? is it because my `get_binary` function uses `select(Host)` ? thanks

Comment: I've been trying to connect 3 tables now in a nested structure. I added another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74725931/deep-nesting-response-model-in-fastapi-using-sqlmodel would be great if you could help. thanks a lot.